# SOQL Queries using the Rest API results are close to half that of the Salesforce reports

Tags: soql, rest-api, reporting

I have a query in SOQL

```
SELECT+Event.Id,Event.CreatedDate,Event.StartDateTime,Event.EndDateTime,Event.Subject,Event.DurationInMinutes,Event.OwnerId,Event.Status__c,Event.Intro_meeting_summary__c,Event.Contact__c,Event.Lead__c,Event.Meeting_Set_Platform__c+from+Event+where+((CreatedDate=LAST_N_YEARS:2+OR+CreatedDate=THIS_YEAR))+AND+((Subject='Intro Meeting'))+ORDER+BY+Lead__c+ASC,CreatedDate+ASC
```

(This is formatted for the REST API call).

But with the filters and the object that I am calling from, I see about 465 results from this query. However, when I run the same concept through the Report, getting all events with Subject = 'Intro Meeting' and within the last 2 years, I get 884 results.

Also, I have checked for continuation with `nextRecordsUrl` and that isn't the issue. And I am using the same user for both.

What's the reason for the massive discrepancy and how do I fix?

Cheers

Comment: Have you checked for and processed continuation with the `nextRecordsUrl` as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm)?

Comment: @PhilW, I have.

Comment: An important detail! I suggest you [edit] the question to clarify what you have done.

Comment: The other point is likely, are you using the same user to run the query in both cases? If not, are there sharing implications?

Comment: @PhilW, will do. I am using the same user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer. It was a setting difference. In the report, I was looking at both Tasks and Events and in the query I am only look at events. I removed Tasks from the report and they are both returning the same answer.

Comment: This is a good answer that others find useful. You could accept your own answer.